# Did Allah really give us choices to choose for being human or not?

Tags: allah, islamic-basis, creation

So I wondering…

I’ve found one similar question like this on this site and already read the answers that showed up but I don’t quite really satisfied yet. (I’m not quite sure if it’s okay to just put some usernames so I wouldn’t. I hope this will be okay too, hope you get what I mean).

So, I have this question from watched one of Video of Zakir Naik on youtube. This is the link of the video that I had watched just in case there’s anybody want to watch it or take a look or anything : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nr6TPAVE1RU&t=545s

So, referring from that video, Zakir Naik mentioned about Surah Al Ahzaab [33] : 72 for answering this question, i guess.

Surah Al Ahzaab [33] : 72 :
“Truly, we did offer the Amanah to the heavens and the earth, and the mountains, but they declined to bear it and were afraid of it. But man bore it. Verily, he was unjust and ignorant.”

I get this from : http://www.quran4u.com/tafsir%20ibn%20kathir/033%20Ahzab.htm

So the problem is, I can’t see the relation between the question and the *verse* (is that right word to say this?) because of the question is more like **ask to: do you want to be human or else** and what written in that verse is **word: man** and this making me assume that we are all already being human when we asked. And word **Amanah**, isn't this just make this verse more likely, **offer the Amanah to human** not **asking do you want to be human or just pass?**

So, am I misinterpreting this?
Or am I missed something so that’s why now I'm asking this to get more suitable answer?
Is there any more verse or hadith or something that has more clear explanation?

I hope I explained this right so everyone gets what I mean.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The verse refers to the Amanah, and that is the responsibility of doing right and avoiding wrong.

It means Allah offered the responsibility to Man, and Man accepted. The "Man" in this verse refers to either Adam (AS) or all humans in general like some scholars said.

The question was not "do you want to be human" but rather "do you want to take the responsibility."

Comment: Thank you for answering my question :) But, would you mind to elaborate your answer?

Comment: I get it that the verse is refers to the Amanah. But as long as I remember and when I watched the video again, at the 7.43 minute, based on what I heard of, Zakir Naik says, “It is the human being. You were fools who said we want to be human being, you and i. You and I were fool.”

Comment: And at the 8.10 minute, also based on what I heard of, Zakir Naik says, “Almighty God says in the Qur’an : Do you want to be a human being? If you become a human being you can become superior to an Angel or can get Inferior. If you don’t want to become a human being just pass.”

Comment: And in Surah Al Ahzaab [33] : 72 :
“Truly, we did offer the Amanah to the heavens and the earth, and the mountains, but they declined to bear it and were afraid of it. But man bore it. Verily, he was unjust and ignorant.”

Comment: I think the part of being human is essential here because based of The Verse, “The Amanah ever offered to the heavens and the earth, and the mountains, but they declined to bear it and were afraid of it.”
Then,
“But man bore it. Verily, he was unjust and ignorant.”

Comment: @Shaafa You're looking at it too deeply. What Dr. Zakir Naik meant was you were offered free will. He used the word human to mean free will because it is synonymous to free will in many cases.

Comment: But this free will... 
The heavens, the earth, the mountains could declined this Amanah so doesn't that mean that the other creations have this free will just like the human? 

And it’s clearly says that Man is so unjust and ignorant and because of having this natural traits, we’ll obviously always willing to take this Amanah?

Comment: I just... Why Allah asked me : Do you want to take The Amanah when i have free will to decline or take it but I'm being asked by Allah when I'm in condition of being human who have this ignorant and unjust traits?

I feel like... So unfair. Why don't Allah asked me when I'm in condition of being neutral creation which have neutral traits too?

Is this probably possible?

Comment: @Shaafa You're overthinking it. Allah simply gave them a choice. They chose like that. The humans are ignorant and unjust if they fail to fulfill the responsibility. They are good and pious if they fulfill the responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, It is clear that the verse says about choice of taking **Amanah** not choice of being Human or not.

> So the problem is, I can’t see the relation between the question and
> the verse

```
Al-`Awfi reported that Ibn `Abbas said, "Al-Amanah means obedience.
```

[Tafsir Ibn Kathir](http://www.alim.org/library/quran/AlQuran-tafsir/TIK/33/72)

From watching his video, I think Dr. Zakir Naik was trying to point out that Allah didn't force us the Amanah (responsibility,duties,obedience) Rather we took it upon ourselves. So we can't blame Allah for that.

Comment: @Shaafa so you didn't got your answer?

Comment: I got my answer for what I asked here but not yet for what i truly mean by asking this question.